# Взаимозависимые чекбоксы React

Tags: reactjs

Есть главная компонента с checkbox, в ней еще несколько компонентов со своими checkbox . При нажатии на checkbox  родительской компоненты, все checkbox дочерней становятся true, при отжимании соответственно false. Когда все checkbox в дочерних компонентах становятся true, родительская должна стать тоже true, когда все checkbox в состоянии true, при отжимании одной дочерней, родительский тоже должен отжаться, также если несколько нажато , то при нажатии на родительский, оставшиеся тоже должны стать true. Помогите решить уже несколько дней бьюсь над этой задачей.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

P.S. Задачу все-таки решил, оставлю будущему поколению) 
Решение задачи: https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-lichterman-noucg?file=/src/MainCheckbox.js

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)